# Safari won't set cookie from same domain (different subdomain)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, cookies, safari

I use a Rails backend and React frontend. I recently deployed my app to Heroku using the following naming convention: `app-name-frontend.herokuapp.com` and `app-name-backend.herokuapp.com`, so the domain is the same. However, when I send a cookie from the api to frontend, I can see the cookie being sent but its never saved. My cors is setup as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'app-name-frontend.herokuapp.com'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
      credentials: true
  end
end
```

And I set my Cookie as follow:

```
{ 
  value: JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: user.id), 
  expires: 1.day,
  httponly: true,
  secure: true,
  same_site: :lax,
  domain: :all
}
```

Since I have domain as :all this means that it should work on all domains and subdomains, and since both are on the domain `herokuapp.com` shouldn't Safari set the cookie? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try with same_site: :none. If it works, it will break Chrome. Take a loot at https://github.com/github/secure_headers.

Answer (score 0):

May be the `HttpOnly` attribute is added in your cookie settings. If the HttpOnly flag is included in the HTTP response header, the cookie cannot be accessed through the client-side script. You can find a detailed explanation [here](https://www.cookiepro.com/knowledge/httponly-cookie/)